# Upload files to Dropbox using HTTP

Tags: http, dropbox, nativescript

I have a NativeScript project and i have to upload a .db file using Dropbox v2 method. On triggering button always create a file with size 0b. Some one please guide me to upload content. What I have tried is follows

```
http.request({
        url: "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer abcfblaabla7384',
        'Dropbox-API-Arg' : 
        '{"path":"/dbFile/'+file.name+'","mode":"add","autorename":true}',
        }, 
        }).then(function (response) {   
        console.log("dropbox response is"+response);
        }, function (e) {
                console.log("Error occurred " + e);
});
```

Comment: you are nit sending the file.

Comment: As bhavin said, you don't appear to actually be sending any file data, so the resulting 0 byte file is expected. It appears you can include data using nativescript's http client via the `'content'` field: https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http#post